# Solving a BVP using scipy.solve_bvp where the function returns an array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, differential-equations

This is a very general question as I feel that my errors are resulting from some misunderstanding of how `scipy.solve_bvp` works. I have a function `def` that takes an array of 12 numbers and returns a list of the system of differential equations for a given time, with shape (2,6). I will have a one dimensional array of length n for my timesteps and then an array `y`of input values with shape (12,n). My code aims to take simulate the motion of earth and mars over a 1000 day period subject to boundary conditions; at t=0 positions = `rpast` (the corresponding velocities are returned by the function `find_vel_past()`), the positions and velocities at t=1000 are given by `rs` and `vs` respectively. My code is at the bottom with the two functions I'm trying to solve above:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import signal

G       = 6.67408e-11 # m^3 s^-1 kg^-2
AU      = 149.597e9 # m
Mearth  = 5.9721986e24 # kg
Mmars   = 6.41693e23 # kg
Msun    = 1.988435e30 # kg
day2sec = 3600 * 24 # seconds in one day

rs = [[-4.8957151e10, -1.4359284e11, 501896.65],  # Earth
      [-1.1742901e11, 2.1375285e11, 7.3558899e9]] # Mars (units of m)
vs = [[27712., -9730., -0.64148], # Earth
      [-20333., -9601., 300.34]]  # Mars (units of m/s)
# positions of the planets at (2019/6/2)-1000 days
rspast = [[1.44109e11, -4.45267e10, -509142.],   # Earth
          [1.11393e11, -1.77611e11, -6.45385e9]] # Mars
def motions(t, y):

    rx1,ry1,rz1, rx2,ry2,rz2, vx1,vy1,vz1, vx2,vy2,vz2 = y
    drx1 = vx1
    dry1 = vy1
    drz1 = vz1
    drx2 = vx2
    dry2 = vy2
    drz2 = vz2

    GMmars  = G*Mmars
    GMearth = G*Mearth
    GMsun   = G*Msun

    rx12  = rx1 - rx2
    ry12  = ry1 - ry2
    rz12  = rz1 - rz2
    xyz12 = np.power(np.power(rx12,2) + np.power(ry12,2) + np.power(rz12,2), 1.5)
    xyz1  = np.power(np.power(rx1, 2) + np.power(ry1, 2) + np.power(rz1, 2), 1.5)
    xyz2  = np.power(np.power(rx2, 2) + np.power(ry2, 2) + np.power(rz2, 2), 1.5)

    dvx1 = -GMmars  * rx12 / xyz12 - GMsun * rx1 / xyz1
    dvy1 = -GMmars  * ry12 / xyz12 - GMsun * ry1 / xyz1
    dvz1 = -GMmars  * rz12 / xyz12 - GMsun * rz1 / xyz1
    dvx2 =  GMearth * rx12 / xyz12 - GMsun * rx2 / xyz2
    dvy2 =  GMearth * ry12 / xyz12 - GMsun * ry2 / xyz2
    dvz2 =  GMearth * rz12 / xyz12 - GMsun * rz2 / xyz2

    return np.array([drx1,dry1,drz1, drx2,dry2,drz2,
                     dvx1,dvy1,dvz1, dvx2,dvy2,dvz2])

def find_vel_past():
    daynum=1000
    ts=np.linspace(0,-daynum*day2sec,daynum)
    angles=np.zeros([daynum,2])
    trange =(ts[0],ts[-1])
    fi=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rs+vs))
    sol= integrate.solve_ivp(earth_mars_motion,trange,fi,t_eval=ts, max_step=3*day2sec,dense_output=True)
    return(sol.y[0:6][:,-1])
##return an array of six velocities at this time 
def estimate_errors_improved():
    daynum=1000
    ##generating np arrays for bouundary conditions
    a=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(find_vel_past()))
    rpast=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rspast))
    acond=np.concatenate([rpast,a])
    bcond=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rs+vs))
    t=np.linspace(0,daynum*day2sec,daynum)
    y=np.zeros(([12,daynum]))
    y[:,0]=acond
    def bc(ya,yb):
        x=yb-bcond
        return np.array(x)
    sol = integrate.solve_bvp(earth_mars_motion1,bc,t,y,verbose=2)
    data1=np.transpose(sol.sol(t))
    angles=np.zeros(daynum)
    for i in range(daynum):      
        angles[i]=angle_between_planets(np.transpose(sol.sol(t)[:,0]))
    x = t/day2sec
    plt.plot(x,angles)
    plt.show()
estimate_errors_improved()
```

I think that the reason my code isnt working is due to some error in the shapes of arrays that are being passed. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong so I can fix things.
The output for `sol.sol(t)` I'm getting is:

```
 Iteration    Max residual  Max BC residual  Total nodes    Nodes added  
Singular Jacobian encountered when solving the collocation system on iteration 1. 
Maximum relative residual: nan 
Maximum boundary residual: 2.14e+11
[[ 1.44109e+11  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00 ...  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
   0.00000e+00]
 [-4.45267e+10  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00 ...  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
   0.00000e+00]
 [-5.09142e+05  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00 ...  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
   0.00000e+00]
 ...
 [         nan          nan          nan ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 [         nan          nan          nan ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 [         nan          nan          nan ...          nan          nan
           nan]]
```

Comment: According to the docs the function must return an array with the same layout as `y`, a (12,n) shape.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to solve? The theoretical solution is completely determined by the positions and velocities at `t=1000`, you can just integrate backwards to `t=0`, any differences you get are numerical and measurement errors. What did you get as result of that? What did you intend to compute with the boundary value solver? The velocities assuming that the positions are exact?

Comment: I want to compute a new interpolated solution over the interval t=-1000,t=0 to compute a more accurate solution for future positions of earth and mars, between times t=0,t=1000. I have used solve IVP to give me a trial solution for t=-1000.

Comment: More accurate than what? Was the aim some kind of least-error computation? Are you aware that `solve_bvp` has a standard tolerance of `1e-3` and is in general more experimental than the IVP solvers? If you are concerned about the accuracy of the solution, why do you not control the tolerances of the solvers? The scales involved are far away from where the default tolerances are sensible. Also, the difference in scales of positions and velocities is barely at the boundary of the sensible, it might improve results to rescale the numbers visible to the solver.

Comment: For this problem we have been specifically asked to use solve_bvp, having already used solve_ivp previously to do the same sorts of things. I have spent a long time trying to get something sensible out, my latest problem is that the shapes of the function called within the solve bvp_problem has array sizes that fluctuates between (12,1000) and (12,999) as discussed in another question, i posted after having implemented the first suggestion above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799629/operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-12-999-12-1000-error-us

Comment: But you do not have a BVP, a boundary value problem with boundary conditions on both boundaries. Why would you expect a better result from a more unstable solver? Why not use the IVP solution to initialize the BVP solver? BVP solvers critically depend on the initial curve, as there can be multiple solutions, and for non-linear problems there can be regions in the trajectory space that have no descend direction towards a correct solution.

Comment: Using the exact positions as boundary conditions, I get the corrected velocities as `rs_neu = [ [ 2.77086293e+04 -9.72734103e+03 -9.96361574e-02], [-2.03298922e+04 -9.60056733e+03  3.02859561e+02] ]`, which are different in the 3rd to 4th digit. One also has to consider that the mass and gravitation constants are not as exact as necessary to get meaningful corrections to the given positions and velocities.

Answer (score 0):

a few problems I think. Firstly the only reason for trying to 'run back' to the -1000 day point as far as I can see would be to obtain a good y estimate to pass to solve_bvp.

to do this simply reverse the initial velocities and run a similation to +1000 days. once you have done this flip the resulting sol.y arrays and they should serve as a good estimate for solve_bvp.

Next, you dont actually need vel past, boundary conditions of the initial position and the t=0 velocity will do perfectly.

This brings us to the next problem, your Boundary condition function looks mistaken.

it should look something like this.

\\

```
def bc(ya, yb):

return np.array([ya[0]-1.44109e11,ya[1] +4.45267e10,ya[2]+509142.,ya[3]-1.11393e11,ya[4]+1.77611e11,ya[5]-6.45385e9,yb[6]-27712.,
                 yb[7]+9730.,yb[8]+0.64148,yb[9]+20333.,yb[10]+9601.,yb[11]-300.34])
```

\\

Final note: you will most likley have to increase the number of nodes in the solve_bvp problem to

hope this helps