# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,999) (12,1000) error using scipy.integrate.solve_BVP

Tags: python, scipy

I have previously asked a question where I asked about where I was generally going wrong with my attempts to solve the BVP here: [Solving a BVP using scipy.solve_bvp where the function returns an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792981/solving-a-bvp-using-scipy-solve-bvp-where-the-function-returns-an-array)

One of the responses I received while answering this stated that the function that i was passing to  `solve_bvp()` was not of shape (12,1000) as per the documentation. I have rectified this by creating a function which generates solutions with the required shape, by first initialising a 12 by 1000 array and then setting each of the 12 arrays of shape 1000 equal to the value of its associated differential equation for each time point at which my functon is called. The code I have written is below, with the new code clearly annotated.

```py
##find our velocity at time t=-1000, where the BVP is started from 
def find_vel_past():
    daynum=1000
    ts=np.linspace(0,-daynum*day2sec,daynum)
    angles=np.zeros([daynum,2])
    trange =(ts[0],ts[-1])
    fi=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rs+vs))
    sol= integrate.solve_ivp(earth_mars_motion,trange,fi,t_eval=ts, max_step=3*day2sec,dense_output=True)
    return(sol.y[0:6][:,-1])
##return an array of six velocities at this time 
def estimate_errors_improved():
    daynum=1000
    ##generating np arrays for bouundary conditions
    a=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(find_vel_past()))
    rpast=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rspast))
    acond=np.concatenate([rpast,a])
    bcond=np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(rs+vs))
    t=np.linspace(0,daynum*day2sec,daynum)
    y=np.zeros(([12,daynum]))
    y[:,0]=acond
    ## THE FUNCTION I HAVE UPDATED AS PER ADVICE RECIEVED
    def earth_mars_motion1(t,y):
        x=np.zeros([12,daynum])
        y1=earth_mars_motion(t,y[:,0])
        for i in range(daynum):
            for i in range(len(y)):
                x[i]=y1[i] 
        return x
    def bc(ya,yb):
        a=ya.ravel()[0:6]-bcond[0:6]
        b=yb.ravel()[0:6]-rpast
        c=np.array([a,b])
        return np.reshape(c,(12))
        #return np.concatenate(ya.ravel()[0:6]-bcond[0:6],yb.ravel()[0:6]-rpast)
    sol = integrate.solve_bvp(earth_mars_motion1,bc,t,y,verbose=1)
    data1=np.transpose(sol.sol(t))
    angles=np.zeros(daynum)
    print(sol.sol(t))
    for i in range(daynum):      
        angles[i]=angle_between_planets(np.transpose(sol.sol(t)[:,0]))
        x = t/day2sec
    plt.plot(x,angles)
    plt.show()
estimate_errors_improved()
```

The output I am getting is: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,999) (12,1000)`. Could anyone please provide a quick solution to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `integrate.solve.bvp(fun,bc,t,x)` works by iterating over the time steps in the problem and plugging into fun. Each time it does this, the input for t gets shorter. Your x that is returned should also be shortened at each step. Try replacing `x=np.zeros([12,daynum])` with `x=np.zeros([12,len(t)])`, and adjust the code following this to match.